# create an installer who executes .reg file

Tags: windows-installer

I want to create a .exe installer. I am trying to do it with iexpress wizard. The problem comes when after selecting all the files that goes in the installer, in the step "install program to launch" I want to put a .reg file to be executed after the installation (in the Post Install Command field). I choose the .reg file that I want but it gives me an error and don't let me to continue. I try to create a .inf file also but it is still giving me an error.

How can I manage to make this .reg file to execute after the installation?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do this?  It's considered an anti-pattern from the windows installer perspective because the execution would run out of process.  This would introduce a host of problems such as the inability to perform rollbacks or easily transform the MSI.

A better approach is to import the reg file into the MSI's Registry table at build time.  How you do that depends on what tool you are using to author the MSI.